# TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null in reactJS

Tags: javascript, html, json, reactjs

in `.js` file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import data from './list.json';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
function print_data(){
    var output="<tb>";
    for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        output+='<tr>';
        output+='<td>'+i.toString()+"</td>";
        output+='<td>'+data[i]["a"]+"</td>";
        output+='<td>'+data[i]["b"]+"</td>";
        output+='<td>'+data[i]["c"]+"</td>";
        output+='</tr>';
    }
    return output;
}
window.document.getElementById("output").innerHTML= print_data();
```

in `.html` file

```
    <table>
      <thead>
        <td>No</td>
        <td>a</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>c</td>
      </thead>
    </table>
```

I'm sure that the json file is non-null, but the error is still occur.

Comment: You have no element with that ID in the HTML!

Comment: Your HTML contains no element with the `id` of `"output"`.  This also *really* doesn't look like how React does things, so if your intent is to use React then you should probably start with their tutorial.

Comment: Mixing direct DOM manipulation and React is generally a really bad idea anyway.

Comment: you should consider watching some tutorials on `React` before getting started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below sample is how you would do it in React. I would suggest you to go through the React Doc: https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>

<div id="app_root"></div>    
<script type="text/babel">
// Constants representing JSON Data.
const items = ["A", "B", "C"];

const Table = () => {

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
      {
        items && items.map(item => (
          <tr key={item}>
            <td>{item}</td>
          </tr>
        ))
      }
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<Table />, document.getElementById("app_root"));

</script>
```